# Assigning values to properties and reusing the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have some code like this.  But imagine that there are hundreds of lines like this all duplicated across multiple functions.

```
MyClass.prop1 = doingsomething("test1");
MyClass.prop2 = doingsomething("test55");
```

I want to reuse my code... how can I do it?

I want to do something like this:

```
    foreach(ClassInfo)
{
    dosomethingAssignment(ClassInfo.propertiesToAssign[i], ClassInfoStringIPassedToFunctionInFirstExample[i]);
}
```

Maybe this isn't the way to do this in C#, but what is the best way to reuse my code?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a class

```
public class MyClassAssigments
{
    public string PropertiesToAssign { get; set; }
    public string ClassInfoStringIPassedToFunctionInFirstExample{ get; set; }
}
```

And say a List which holds those data

```
List<MyClassAssigments> MyData
```

Then you can have something like:

```
PropertyInfo[] pInfos = typeof(MyClassType).GetProperties(); //Assuming MyClass is of Type MyClassType
Foreach (MyClassAssigments aData In MyData)
{
   PropertyInfo eachPInfo in pInfos.Where(W => W.Name == aData.PropertiesToAssign)).SingleOrDefault(); 
   If (eachPInfo != null)
   {
      eachPInfo.SetValue(MyClass, doingsomething(aData.ClassInfoStringIPassedToFunctionInFirstExample), null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that will reflectively instantiate the property, given an array of PropertyInfos or property string names:

```
var properties = MyClass.GetType().GetProperties();
var values = new [] {"test1", "test55", ... };

for(var i=0; i<properties.Count; i++)
   DoSomethingAndAssign(properties[i], values[i], MyClass);

public void DoSomethingAndAssign(PropertyInfo prop, string theValue, Object theClass)
{
   var setValue = /*do anything you want based on theValue before setting*/

   //will throw an exception if theClass is null, theClass doesn't have the property,
   //or the property cannot be set to a value of setValue's type.
   prop.SetValue(theClass, setValue, null);
}
```

Be aware this will be much slower than statically assigning the values, as reflective algorithms usually are. It will also compile no matter what the structure of MyClass is, so you'll have to extensively test it at runtime.

Another possible method, if your class contains a lot of very similar properties, is to define an indexer. An indexer makes the class look like an indexed collection, like an array or List. It would likely involve a reflective algorithm or switch statement to turn the value into a , though. A far easier and more elegant method would be to have MyClass contain a Dictionary of the properties you want to iterate through, and tie the property accessors and the indexer to the dictionary.

All of this basically either hides the list of property assignments, or implements a less efficient way of looping through assignments. If you have hundreds of properties, this will save you some typing, but I would look at refactoring that class to reduce or collect its properties. If you have five properties that get set in many places in the system, I would see if a class that knows how to initialize your class is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

This is clear code:

```
Baseball.Mass = 20;
Baseball.InitialVelocity = new velocity(100, 0, 0);
Baseball.Spin = new Spin(0,0,1, 20);
```

This is not clear code:

```
AssignProperties(PropertiesBag, Baseball.PropertiesBag);
```

Ask yourself before you go down this path too far, *why do I want to reuse this code?*  Sometimes it's ok, as in when you're initializing an object (which is what serialization and generator classes are for).  A lot of the time it's not ok, as when you're changing an object during transaction processing.  Keeping the difference clean and clear is important.

Comment: I want to reuse the code because there are 100 properties.  I don't want to have to retype in each of these properties each time.  Also when a new developer comes if I have 7 different functions listing these properties and they add a new one chances are they will forget to add the properties to one of these methods.

Comment: Having 100 properties on a single class is a strong smell that the class is doing way too much.  Is this a class you have access to for refactoring purposes?

Comment: It is a set of data structures that represent information sent from a 3rd party source via xml.

Comment: Can you transform the incoming XML to a common format and rewrite your code to only ever use the version of the assignation function for that common format?  This is how BizTalk, for example, handles multiple incoming formats.  Having multiple functions that all pull into a single data structure sounds like a recipe for unhappiness.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example that does this.
Note that you should better specify mappings using attributes if you're going to reuse this approach in different places.
Also **do not do it unless you're sure it is required**. Reflection-driven code is nice but it can be a monster to debug and maintain if you're not sure what you're doing.

```
class Guy {
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> mappings = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Name", "nameProp" },
        { "Age", "ageProp" }
    };

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void RetrieveProperties (Func<string, object> valueRetriever)
    {
        foreach (var prop in GetType ().GetProperties (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)) {
            var mapping = mappings [prop.Name];
            var value = valueRetriever (mapping);

            prop.SetValue (this, value, null);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return string.Format ("I'm {0}, {1} years old.", Name, Age);
    }
}


public static class Program
{
    static object GetItemPropertyValue (string itemName)
    {
        if (itemName == "nameProp")
            return "John";

        if (itemName == "ageProp")
            return 42;

        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    public static void Main ()
    {
        var john = new Guy ();
        john.RetrieveProperties (GetItemPropertyValue);

        Console.WriteLine (john);
    }
}
```